# Feasibility of Flywheel-Powered Artillery

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons, energy

As far as it is known, **Flywheels** are extremely efficient in energy storage, with the best even able to replace even the strongest batteries. They are accelerated by electricity to extremely high speeds, maintaining a sizeable amount of rotational kinetic energy.

[image: YOU SPIN ME ROUND]

So far, it is already possible to use Flywheels to power lasers:

https://futurism.com/uk-laser-weapon-dragonfire-energy-flywheel

In a forum, I came across an interesting idea to use a Flywheel's energy to propel bullets in guns and artillery. They said that with a flywheel made of an indestructible and frictionless material, say, Alexander Bolonkin's AB Matter, then you could store up to 10^11 joules in a 1 kg flywheel and fling things at .13 C.

By that idea, I believe that they were thinking of directly converting all of the flywheel's rotational energy to the bullet's kinetic energy.

I therefore ask if it is possible for this direct energy conversion. If that is possible, then the rest should be possible as well, for any flywheel power rating and subsequent bullet kinetic energy.

PS: Any size for the flywheels is fine.

Comment: "indestructible and frictionless material" - I presume the gun and projectiles can be made of this material as well (though it's not quite science-based)?

Comment: Yes. AB-Matter works wonders.

Comment: As a projectile... Deadly, as uninterruptible power supply... Definitely!

Comment: Well, bullets would be kind of hard, but torpedoes on the other hand, hmm...

Answer (score 7):

These kinds of weapons have been envisioned since the American Civil War, and likely before that
[image: Charles Dickinson of Boston Centrifugal Gun]

Demonstrations of these weapons showed they had a very high rate of fire and were extremely inaccurate.  This is because the projectiles have no stabilizing spin orthogonal to the velocity vector.

Once the round leaves the centrifuge, it doesn't accelerate anymore, it travels at a fixed velocity in a straight line until turbulence from traveling through the air causes the round to veer off.   I guess in outer space these weapons would be accurate but in worlds with atmospheres, the flight of the round is dominated by random forces.

If your weapon had a mechanism to impart spin on the projectile, then it would be more accurate.  Modern rifling won't work since there isn't any force to push the projectile through the grooves of the barrel.  The grooves would steal momentum from the round to impart spin, slowing it down considerably.  Fins on the rear (or front) of the projectile could impart spin, but slowly, and at the cost of momentum.  And the spin would take time to build up rotational velocity, so the first few moments out of the barrel the round would be dominated by random forces due to turbulence like an old-time cannonball.

Comment: You could spin the projectiles up to speed while they were in the magazine.  If your centrifugal cannon were build like a wagon wheel, the shells could come down the spokes and be spun by progressively faster brushes until they reached the perimeter and were released.  You could have the brushes mounted on the wheel, or fixed under the wheel with a slot in the magazine so the spinning wheel rubbed the projectiles against the fixed brushes.

Comment: That might work,  I imagine you wouldn't lose too much energy to brush contact.  And, maybe a blast of air or steam from behind to get rear fins to impart some rotational velocity.  To my knowledge, no one has done it yet.  I imagine it is a challenging problem in mechanical engineering

Comment: Accuracy is perhaps not all that big a deal.  Machine guns aren't all that accurate - that's partly why tracer rounds were invented.

Comment: Or, you know, you could just throw giant metal arrows at your target, no spin stabilization required. It's not like [modern tanks do this regularly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour-piercing_fin-stabilized_discarding_sabot) or anything...

Answer (score 1):

As a massive Battlebots fan, I think I have a neat idea for how it could work. A few robots there have used a flywheel to power a flipping arm, able to launch a 250 pound robot several feet in the air. A perfect example is [Blip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzZufNCXaeE). Bullets don't weigh anywhere near 250 pounds, and would end up travelling incredibly fast.

How Blip's mechanism works is it has a flywheel spun by a motor. The flywheel is attached to one half of a clutch system, the other half of which is connected to a bunch of ropes. When the clutch is engaged, these ropes twist, and the bundle shortens. This shortening pulls a lever, which is the arm. If you used a similar setup, make it smack into a bullet, you could launch it at ridiculous velocities. Plus, the air pressure provided by the acceleration would allow rifling.